# PHP form reloads on submit, but resets variables

Tags: php, html, forms

I've been tasked to create a guessing game. A random number is generated and the user tries to guess it. It tells you if you should try a larger or a smaller number, and eventually the user guesses the correct number.

```
<?php
session_start();

if(empty($_SESSION['num_to_guess'])) { $_SESSION['num_to_guess'] = mt_rand(1,99); }

if (!isset($_POST['guess'])) {
    $message = "Welcome to the Odd Number Guessing Game!";
}

elseif (!is_numeric($_POST['guess'])) { //is not numeric
$message = "I don't understand that response. Please enter a number.";
}

elseif ($_POST['guess'] == $_SESSION['num_to_guess']) { //matches
    $message = "Well done! You've found the secret number. Now try to guess another.";
    $_SESSION['num_to_guess'] = mt_rand(1,99);
}

elseif ($_POST['guess'] < $_SESSION['num_to_guess']) { //greater
    $message = "Try a larger number!";
}

elseif ($_POST['guess'] > $_SESSION['num_to_guess']) { //lesser
    $message = "Try a smaller number!";
}

else {
    $message = "I'm terribly confused.";
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>

<head>
<title>Odd Number Guessing Machine!</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1><?php echo $message; ?>

<?php echo $_SESSION['num_to_guess']; ?>

</h1>
<form action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method = "POST">

<p><label for="guess">Try to guess an odd number between 1 and 99:</label> <br/>
<input type="text" id="guess" name="guess" /></p>
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

My problem is the form reloads every time the user submits the data, thereby changing the random number. I'm sure there is a workaround but I just can't seem to find it.

I want to generate a new number ONLY when the correct number is guessed. I tried adding rand() function on the elseif loop where the number is guessed correctly, but that doesn't work.

Please help. :)

Comment: Just replace every $num_to_guess with $_SESSION['num_to_guess']. And never forget to change first assign to this: if(empty($_SESSION['num_to_guess'])) { $_SESSION['num_to_guess'] = 42; }

Comment: This changes the number when it is guessed correctly but it always resets back to 42.

Comment: if(empty($_SESSION['num_to_guess'])) prevents to assign again to 42 and it defines for first time only.

Comment: I tried the if(empty) function. It's still stuck on 42 for some reason.

Comment: Add session_start(); after <?php

Comment: OH MY GOD IT WORKS. THANKS DUDE

Comment: Good job. You can improve your code by change rand to mt_rand. It is 4 times faster and better to guess new numbers.

Comment: Thank you. Another question, is there a convenient way to convert even numbers to odd (or perhaps generate only odd numbers)? Or do I have to use if statements and the modulus operator?
I've updated my original code. If I were to add an if($_SESSION['num_to_guess'] %2 = 1) statement, where would I do that?

Comment: Do you still need help?

Comment: You can use this for generate ODD numbers after rand: if ($_SESSION['num_to_guess'] % 2 == 0) { $_SESSION['num_to_guess'] += 1; }

Comment: This is great. Thank you so very much! I can't find any way to upvote your comment but I would smash that button if there was one!

Comment: No problem dear friend. Your score increase in the future and then you can upvote comments by hovering on left of each comments. Good luck

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Now browser compatible

```
 <?php
 session_start();

 $url_of_page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

 if(!isset($_SESSION['correct_number'])){ 
 // Create random number only when the previous one has been correctly guessed

        $number_to_guess = rand(0,9);

        $_SESSION['correct_number'] = $number_to_guess;

     }

 if(isset($_SESSION['correct_number'])){

         $num_to_guess = $_SESSION['correct_number']; 
  }

 if(isset($_POST['guess'])){

     $guessed_number = trim($_POST['guess']);
     $reg_exp = '/^([0-9]+)$/';
     $reg_exp_match = preg_match($reg_exp,$guessed_number);

 }

 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        if(isset($reg_exp_match)){

            if(!$reg_exp_match){

                 $message = "Enter a number";

             }else{

             if($guessed_number < $num_to_guess){ 
                 // is small

                 $message = "Try a larger number!";

                 }elseif($guessed_number > $num_to_guess){ 
                 // is large

                 $message = "Try a smaller number!";

                 }elseif($guessed_number == $num_to_guess){ 
                 //matches

                 $message = "Well done...You got it";
                 $new_game = TRUE;

                 unset($_SESSION['correct_number']);
                 // A new number can now be created                      
                 }

             }

        }

    }
 ?>

 <!DOCTYPE html> 
 <html>

 <head>
 <title>Odd Number Guessing Machine!</title>
 </head>

 <body>

 <h3>Welcome to the Guessing Machine!</h3>

 <p>
 <?php 
 if(isset($new_game) && ($new_game == TRUE)){ // The correct number

        if(isset($message) && isset($url_of_page)){ 

             echo $message . '. <a href="' . $url_of_page . '">Start a new game</a>'; 

        }

     }else{ // Not the correct number

         if(isset($message)){ echo $message; } 

}
 ?>
 </p>

 <form action="<?php if(isset($url_of_page)){ echo $url_of_page; } ?>" method="POST">

     <p>
        <label for="guess">Enter a number, 0 to 9:</label> <br/>

        <input type="text" id="guess" name="guess" />

     </p>

     <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>

 </form>

 </body>

 </html>
```

Comment: it just says no..not correct over and over. doesn't let me know if i'm hot or cold. :)

Comment: Ok. Then I need some time. Later

Comment: Thank you, in the meanwhile i'll try to understand what you did!

Comment: You will realized that I've reduced the range of random numbers. After it works, that should be the right time to increase the range

Comment: I tried your newer code, it's still giving the same response.

Actually, the logic is working. I can guess the number if i try all from 0-9 but there is no hint whether the guess is higher or lower

Comment: Now you have it. I think

Comment: I'm sorry my friend, but this one doesn't even respond. It just stays on welcome to the guessing machine. 
I'm thankful for all your help so far! I will try using input type hidden. Its just a school project so please don't worry too much!

Comment: I'm sorry. Look at the current update. I've found why it just stays there

Comment: No, we're back to the original problem. Says not correct over and over. :)

Comment: I got it to work. Thank you so much for your help!
Apparently all I needed was a tiny session_start();